# Some images don't appear on in the browser

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website, consisting of 5 pages (e.g. page1.html, page2.html, etc. and following .css sheets). Weirdly, on some pages part of images appears without problem, but others do not. It seems like problem may be with pages/files, since when I tried to use the same image in different html file in place of the appearing image and it showed without problems. I tried using both copying whole url and name of the image with extension(images are in the same directory as the html and css files). Any thoughts?
(I'm using Chrome to view the website)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description"  />
  <title> "animātiō" is "bestowing of life"</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CW1_page1_style.css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Just a small website about animation</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="menu">

        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page0.html">Menu & Navigation</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page1.html">History and Beginnings</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page2.html">Traditional medium</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page3.html">Computer animation</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page4.html">2D or 3D: Which is Better?</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

<div>

  <section id="section-a">
    <div class="box-1">
       The first "animations" were sequences of consecutive images, which would give an illusion of movement.
       At the beginning there existed machines like Praxinoscope - series of images rotated at high speed - and Shadow plays - moving figures on a screen.
       Not to mention the technique known to every child that is a flipbook - conjuring "moving" image upon quickly flipping paper sheets.
  </div >
</section>
<section >
  <section id=section
  <p id="ex" >Examples of machines</p>
  <div class="examples">

   <img class="slide" src='magic-lantern.png' alt='Magic Lantern' />

  <img class="slide" src='zoetrope.gif' alt='Zoetrope'/>

   <img class="slide" src='flip-book.png' alt='Flip-Book'/>

    <img class="slide" src='praxinoscope.png' alt='Praxinoscope'/>


    </div>
</section>
<br />
  <section id="section-c">
    <div class-"box-2">
      The breakthrought began with the invention of motion pictures.
      Hand-drawn and painted animation was prevalent throughout the whole 20th century. From the first short movies of the silent era, to fresh creations with color and soundtrack
      animation started growing in popularity - and bringing more and more profit.
      </div>
      <div class="box-3">
        <img scr="snow-white.jpg" alt="Snow White'"/>
        The first hand-drawn animated movie - Disney's "Snow White" (1937)
        <img scr="disney.jpg" alt="Walt Disney'"/>
        Walt Disney - pioneer of American animation industry
      </div>
  </section>

<section id="section-d">
  <div class="box-3">
After addition of sound and color and subsequent success of Disney, other studios began to produce their own features. This was, no doubt, the golden years for Hollywood animation.
  </div>
  <div class="box-4">
    With the end of the 1950s and growing popolarity of television, stations began to emit various animated productions. A lot of them were cartoons aimed to kids
  </div>
  <div class="box-5">
Major animated productions from the Golden Era of American Televison feature cartoons like "The Flinstons", "Bear Yoggy"
  <br />
  <img scr="felixc.jpg" alt="Felix the Cat"/>
  <img scr="flinstones.jpg" alt="Flinstons"/>
  </div>
</section>


</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: beige;
  font-size: 17px;
}

 /** {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} */
h1 {
  color: #3e3e80;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

#menu {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: green
 }

 #menu a {
   float: left;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }
 #menu a:hover {
  color: #3e3e80;
  background-color: white;
 }

  .slide {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .examples::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: inline-flex;
  }

  #section-c {
    display : inline-flex;
  }
```

Example above: Here first 4 images work, the rest doesn't

And below everything appears no problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description"  />
    <title> "animātiō" is "bestowing of life"</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CW1_page2_style.css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Just a small website about animation</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="menu">

        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page0.html">Menu & Navigation</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page1.html">History and Beginnings</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page2.html">Traditional medium</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page3.html">Computer animation</a>
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Asia/Desktop/Uni/Semestr2/Introduction%20to%20Web%20Technologies/CW1_page4.html">2D or 3D: Which is Better?</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

  <div>
    <section id="section-a">
      <div class="box-0">
      Traditional animation (hand-drawn animation) is the first type of aniamtion that have been used (not counting any machines equipped with slides).
      <br /><br />
      The oldest and used commonly throughtout most of the history of animation,
      recently this style seemed to fall out of grace in favour of computer generated images.
      However, it's still used even nowadays and has many enthusiasts.
      <br />

    </div>
    <div class='box-1'>
      <img class="im" src="aniwork1.jpg" alt="Animator working on" />
    </div >
    <div class="small-fact">
      <img class="im" src="aniwork2.jpg" alt="Animator working on" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-fact">
        Did you know: The standard number of frames is 90 per minute of the movie!
        <br /> <br />
        That makes 8100 drawings for a 90 minutes-long film!
    </div>
    </section>

  <section id="section-b">
    <div class="box-2">
      The process of creating any animated piece starts with storyboards.
       Here, delegated artists prepare rough layouts of the scene, with characters and backgrounds taken into consideration.
      <img  class="board" src="storyboard.jpg" alt="Storyboard" />
    </div>
      <div class="box-3">

       <img class="phase" src="animatic phase.gif" alt="Animatic phase form Avatar: The Last Airbender" />
The next stage is animatic phase - similar to storyboarding, but consisting of key frame (the most important parts of the particular scenes).
  <br /> <br />
  (Above: animatic phase from "Avatar: The Last Airbender")
  <br /> <br />
  (Left: Storyboards indicate on surroundings, as well as the charaters and actions.)
     </div>
    <div class="box-4">
      Afterwards, there's a need to provide the in-between, additional images which will guarantee smoothness of the animation.
      Lastly, it's only the matter of inking and coloring the pages.
        <img class="slide1" src='inking.jpg' alt='Inking a character #1' />
        <img class="slide2" src='ink-color.jpg' alt='Inked and colored character' />

    </div>

  </section>
  <section>

  <div class="examples">
  <p id="ex" >Examples of traditionally animated features</p>
    <img class="pink" src='pinkp.jpg' alt='The Pink Panther'/>
     <img class="pi" src='pinoccio.jpg' alt='Pinoccio'/>
      <img class="lion" src='lion_king.webp' alt='The Lion King'/>
      <img class="eldorado" src='eldorado.jpg' alt='Road to El Dorado'/>


  </div>

</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: beige;
  font-size: 17px;
}
h1 {
  color: #3e3e80;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

#menu {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: brown;
 }

 #menu a {
   float: left;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }
 #menu a:hover {
  color: #3e3e80;
  background-color: white;
 }


  #section-a {
    display: flex;
  }
  #section-a .box-0{
      float: left;
      width: 70%;
      padding: 5px;
  }
  #section-a .box-1 .im{
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #section-a .small-fact{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  #section-a .small-fact .im {
    width: 250px;
    height: 175px;
  }


  #section-b {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
  }

  #section-b .box-2{
    padding: 5px;
  }

  #section-b .box-2 .board {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;

  }

  #section-b .box-3 {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  #section-b .box-3 .phase .{
    width: 100vs;
    height: auto;
  }

   #section-b .box-4{
    padding: 5px;
  }

#section-b .box-4 .slide1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

}
#section-b .box-4 .slide2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 35%;

}


#ex {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline
}


.pink {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.pi {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
  padding: 0px;
}
.lion {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.eldorado {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 65vh;
}

.examples::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: How to check your image file path in your system path

Comment: All image moved to image folder then call images/imagename

Comment: All images that I used/tried to use I downloaded and placed in the same folder as the html and css files edit:trying it now edit2: still nothing

Comment: Are you replaced scr or src in image attributes

Comment: Can you use localhost

Comment: Oh my God, I see it . Thanks, all good here now!

Comment: Please use a validator and formatter in your coding IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just try to replace "scr" attribute by "src"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put all your images on the same folder or assets folder.

Finally, some time, clearing the cache of the browser fix the problem.